# The size of Logits of Roberta model is weird

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

My input size is [8,22]. A batch with 8 tokenized sentences with a length of 22.
I dont want to use the default classifier.

```
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-large")
 
model.classifier=nn.Identity()
```

After model(batch)
The size of result is torch.Size([8, 22, 1024]). I have no idea why. Should it be [8,1024]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `model.classifier` object you have replaced used to be an instance of a `RobertaClassificationHead`. If you take a look at its source code<sup>[1]</sup>, the layer is hard-coded into indexing the first item of the second dimension of its input, which is supposed to be the `[CLS]` token.
By replacing it with an `Identity` you miss out on the indexing operation, hence your output shape.

Long story short, don't assume functionality you haven't verified when it comes to non-own code, huggingface in particular (lots of ad-hoc classes and spaghetti interfaces, least as far as I'm concerned).

---

[1] [source](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/b487096b02307cd6e0f132b676cdcc7255fe8e74/src/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py#L1435)